# searching controller in a web application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring-mvc. In my first tutorial I am having a doubt, we create a servelet of **DispatcherServlet** in web.xml and mark our controller using **@contorller** annotation.
Then using **@Requestmapping** annotation we filter url for function to be invoked.

How Spring searches for controller in the webapp? 
Which function actually invoked in  DispatcherServelet to create a instance of controller class?
Can i have multiple controller in my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How Spring searches for controller in the webapp?

**Spring container scans through all of the packages specified through `@ComponentScan` annotation** (or using `component-scan` in xml config) and when you mark your bean class with stereotype annotation like `@Controller`, Spring container will create the instance (by default singleton scope) of your controller class and maps the url along with the request method type(like `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, etc..). The other stereotype annotation are listed [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/package-tree.html) (like `@Service`, etc..) and the container creates objects for these types as well.

> Which function actually invoked in DispatcherServelet to create a
>   instance of controller class?

**Spring core container creates the instances** for all beans annotated with stereotypes (as explained above during container start up) and then
**`Dispatcherservlet` uses [HandlerMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html) to map the urls to the controller methods** and **`RequestMappingHandlerMapping`** implementation is being used by default and when the request comes, it will be delegated to the respective the controller method, you can look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping).

> Can I have multiple controllers in my application?

Yes, you can define multiple controllers in your application. In a typical web application project, you would see many controller classes each mapped with the respective urls and the business logic being handled through their service classes.

I suggest you refer [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) to understand on how the spring web flow works.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I have multiple controller in my application?

Yes.You can create multiple controller in your application.You can get more idea following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920959/how-many-spring-controller-in-spring3) post.